# Getting an X.509 digital security certificate for IRS AIR A2A web service

Tags: x509, irs

My workplace is looking to add the software developer role to our company's relationship with the IRS. I pulled down the latest PDF's from the IRS AIR site and it pointed me at two certificate authorities to have a certificate issued to us. On the [IdenTrust website](https://www.identrust.com/support/aces), IdenTrust says that as of last month they are no longer issuing the ACES certificates.

My question is, has anyone gotten a confirmation if we are to be using the IGC certificate?

I have verified that I have the latest versions of the PDF's.

**Update**:
We just got an email confirming the information that Das gave. Additionally, the IRS sent us a response to an inquiry we made regarding the certificates, confirming the use of the IGC certificates. They included information that they have updated the Publication 5258 on their site. I've checked the new revision of the publication and it does list the IdenTrust IGC certificate as one of two possibilities.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: My workplace went through IdenTrust as our Certificate Provider.  Beyond that, I don't know the specifics of the type of Cert we purchased.  However, I would think there would be a solution for you with IdenTrust.

Comment: We contacted the IRS asking about the certificate situation and mentioned the IdenTrust IGC certificates. We were told that they would look into the issue and contact us by the end of the week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the response I got from the IRS when asking about this specific issue back on August 24th.

> IGC certificates have been approved by the General Services Administration (GSA) to replace discontinued ACES certificates.  We are in the process of updating our publication with this information.

Comment: Thank you. We were still waiting for a response back from the IRS.